# Adding an <a> tag to a list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, append

I am trying to add an `<a>` tag to a list of `li` with the help of jQuery.

The html looks like this:

```html
<div class="level one">
      <ul class="kitchen-tools">
      <li class="my list"></li>
      <li class="my list"></li>
      <li class="my list"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I created an empty `<a>` tag with jQuery. Unfortunately I can't find a way to add this `<a>` tag to all my `<li>` (I tried the jQuery append method).

```js
 let aTag = $("a");
     $(".my list").append(aTag);
```

I am new to coding, so I am sure I am doing a silly mistake here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want all the `<li>` elements to have an `<a>` or just one? Also note that `$(".my list")` is incorrect. You need a `.` in `$(".my list")` since `list` is a class. So `$(".my.list")`

Comment: all the <li> should have an <a>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.my.list').append('<a>')` is all you need:

```js
$('.my.list').append('<a>')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="level one">
  <ul class="kitchen-tools">
    <li class="my list"></li>
    <li class="my list"></li>
    <li class="my list"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Since your list items have two classes you need to select them with `$('.my.list')`

Comment: Thanks. Since I want to append the empty tag that I have created with jQuery (`let aTag = $("a");`), will this work? The idea is to later fill in the necessary content in the empty `<a>` tag called aTag.

Comment: @Detla888 yes, you can use a variable for the anchor, but it would need to be `let aTag = $("<a>");`, not `let aTag = $("a");`